# Can someone please suggest a better naming scheme when class variables are same as formal parameters received by a constructor in c#

Tags: c#

```
class sample
{   
    int varOne, varTwo;    
    sample(int varOne, int varTwo)
    {
      this.varOne= varOne;
      this.varTwo= varTwo;
    }
}
```

In the above piece of code what will be the best naming convention to distinguish between the formal parameters received with the class variables? I know that 'this' keyword distinguishes between the both. But is there any naming convention applied in similar situation? Thanks for any help.

Comment: [Naming Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xzf533w0%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: Unfortunately the Naming Guidelines do not cover the question explicitly as far as I can see; [implicitly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3f80506d%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) they go with the OP. - Very often I see a simple underscore appended to the constructor parms. But since the scope is only within the constructor the whole point is somewhat [moot](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/96435/the-point-is-moot)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like to use capital letters for class names
and the "m_" prefix for private class variables.

so given your sample:

```
class Sample
{
    private int m_varOne;
    private int m_varTwo;

    Sample(int varOne, int varTwo)
    {
        this.m_varOne = varOne;
        this.m_varTwo = varTwo;
    }
}
```

Comment: To each his own, but to me this looks weird..